# Laravel 8, swiftmailer, stream_socket_enable_crypto() certificate did not match expected CN

Tags: laravel, email, lets-encrypt

My web server shares the same IP as my mail server. Two Lets Encrypt certificates are in use: one for the mail server, one for the web server. Emailing works perfectly when using e.g. Apple Mail to send/receive emails from/to my account with this server, third-party tests report that the relevant DNS entries are correct, certificates are in order, etc.

And yet, Laravel throws the following error when an email is queued to be sent (though strangely not in 100% of email use cases):

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`mail.xxx' did not match expected CN=`www.xxx'
```

In Laravel's .env file, MAIL_HOST is set to "mail.xxx".

I have tried both "www.xxx" and "mail.xxx" for the `MAIL_HOST` parameter.
´
I have tried both "smtp" and "sendmail" for the `MAIL_MAILER` parameter.

I am aware that one can deactivate SSL (i.e `'verify_peer' => false`), but this is not the sort of solution I am willing to implement.

**Question**: Can I somehow inform swiftmailer/Laravel to 'expect' the mail.xxx CN, seeing as it seems to ignore the MAIL_HOST parameter in .env?

Thank you in advance!